# How to charge Google Places API and Google Maps API as well?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have been trying to use Googles Places API and its following functionalities such as "Autocomplete" or "PlacesService" to get info per marker as well. 
I have install google places module but I don't know how to charge the PLACES library. I use the following JS and put it into my index.pug (html) but then the "map" is not loading

`<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places"></script>`

I originally used this
`script(async='', defer='', src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap")`
to charge the google maps api - and the map therefore.

Could someone enlighten me? 
Thank you very much in advance..

Answer (score 0):

Just have a look at their ["getting started"](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial) and put that in your HTML:

```
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places&callback=initMap"></script>
```